# How do I install this to get the printer working?

Tags: printing, samsung

Samsung Xpress SL-C430W Full Driver and Software Package (deb)
http://samsungdrivers.co/samsung-xpress-sl-c430w-driver-download/

I convinced my Mrs to change to ubuntu and now her printer wont work.

If i need to use tar files can please somebody give me step by step including the file name because it baffles me. I've tried and tried. Help please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would be wary of the site you give; I would suggest keeping clear;

if you look at this post [Samsung ML2545 printer on Ubuntu 18.04 - a brick?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1035371/samsung-ml2545-printer-on-ubuntu-18-04-a-brick/1035495#1035495)

I have given advice on how to install the official ULD that Samsung provide; yes, commands are needed but if you copy them; paste into the terminal is right-click at the text prompt in the terminal; look for PASTE in the menu that appears ........ keep us in touch how it goes