# Samsung ML2545 printer on Ubuntu 18.04 - a brick?

Tags: printing, ubuntu-drivers

I upgraded to Ubuntu 18.4 and my Samsung ML2545 printer stopped working.   Can't find a driver for it on the OS itself, can't find one at Samsung, HP, or elsewhere on the net.  Does anyone know of a source, or do I have a brick on my hands?

Comment: How is it connected, USB, network cable, WiFi?

Comment: usb cable .......................

Answer (score 1):

if you go here https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/samsung-ml-2545-laser-printer-series/19134776 you can see a link to download and **SAVE** the compressed ULD (unified linux driver) that Samsung provide for their devices; you can see HP host this now;

it comes down as **uld_V1.00.39_01.17.tar.gz**

so if you open a terminal; 
copy each command below  and paste each command into the terminal; 
hit ENTER after each paste

```
cd Downloads

tar -zxvf uld_V1.00.39_01.17.tar.gz

cd uld

sudo ./install.sh
```

and that should install the needed;

Comment: Thank you very much, i though it has something to do with that file, i should have trusted my instincts and tried that. unbelievably simple. 3 days I've been trying.

Comment: delighted to hear it is all working; enjoy